# Does compiler detect variables that are calculated more than one time?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

My question concerns the following construction :

```
uint16_t flag = 0x1f;
while (curCase) {
        if ((curCase->i == i) && (curCase->j == j)) flag ^= 0x10;
        if ((curCase->i == i-1) && (curCase->j == j)) flag ^= 0x01;         
        if ((curCase->i == i) && (curCase->j == j+1)) flag ^= 0x02;
        if ((curCase->i == i+1) && (curCase->j == j)) flag ^= 0x04;
        if ((curCase->i == i) && (curCase->j == j-1)) flag ^= 0x08;
        if (!(flag ^ 0xf0)) return; // if none of the neighbors are candidates (ignore first bits)
        curCase = curCase->suiv;
    }
```

curCase is just an element of a linked list with 2 int attributes i and j, and the next element suiv;

Knowing that my program runs on a single thread and that consequently pointed values can't change during an iteration of the while;

I was wondering if the compiler was smart enough (and I guess the answer is yes, but I'd like to be sure) to detect that the code requires to calculate the pointers curCase->i and curCase->j 5 times when I could have just declared 2 temporary pointers and assigned curCase->i and curCase->j at the beginning of the loop;

And more generally if it detects variables that are calculated more than once and optimize in consequence.

I've tested with different list sizes with both options and I haven't found one to be much faster than the other.

Comment: I would say yes to both. You won't notice a change in a self test unless you run a very large test loop. Look at the underlying machine code yourself to see the difference with optimizing off and on to see.

Comment: As long as `curCase->i` and `curCase->j` are not `volatile` accesses, then the compiler _could_ perform constant folding optimization. But you'd need to check the generated code to find out for sure.

Comment: @johnelemans how would you suggest that I proceed, and/or do you have good resources as to how to do that? I have never tried looking at machine code before, but I'd like to go to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a code this size it is very difficult to find performance differences based on compiler optimizations (just a comment). I *think* that is totally up to the compiler implementation, it could be done, however that depends on the analysis of the scope.

To test the hypotheses I adapted your code a little bit to use [Compile Explorer](https://godbolt.org) as follows:

```
struct cur { int i; int j; void * suiv;} typedef cur;
int i;
int j;

void function(cur *curCase) {
    int flag = 0x1f;
    while (curCase) {
        if ((curCase->i == i) && (curCase->j == j)) flag ^= 0x10;
        if ((curCase->i == i-1) && (curCase->j == j)) flag ^= 0x01;         
        if ((curCase->i == i) && (curCase->j == j+1)) flag ^= 0x02;
        if ((curCase->i == i+1) && (curCase->j == j)) flag ^= 0x04;
        if ((curCase->i == i) && (curCase->j == j-1)) flag ^= 0x08;
        if (!(flag ^ 0xf0)) return; // if none of the neighbors are candidates (ignore first bits)
        curCase = curCase->suiv;
    }
}
```

And it seems that the assembly code for gcc and CLang do not isolate the instructions you mentioned.

You can find the code analysis here: https://godbolt.org/z/afQxxd

Comment: Thank you. I did not know of this site!

Comment: Be sure to set optimization to O2 or O3 when doing this type of work or the compiler won't optimize this much.  Also will need a driver that uses the data or the compiler will rightly dead strip everything.

Comment: @Balocre, you may use this kind of flags in Compiler Explorer, I did not in my test, but that is true, you have to instruct the compiler on the level of optimization that you want.

Answer (score 2):

As I stated in the comments, you must tell the compiler to optimize or it won't do much.  Also, flag is unused so i modified it to be returned so the compiler will care about it.

Here is the same example slightly modified to return the `flag` and with optimizations so that you can see what the compiler really can do.

https://godbolt.org/z/B_maur

Comment: Thank you! I in fact use the flag, but since my question was only about this portion of code I removed everything which was not related to the question.